# How Can I Put a Text inside a Data Frame without Getting an Error Message

Tags: r, tibble

I have been trying to imitate the use of Emily Dickinson's short text in *Text Mining with R: A Tidy Approach* by Julia Silge and David Robinson, using a slightly longer text by Philip Larkin. However, although the text loads in R fine, I cannot make it into a data frame without getting the following error message:

```r
> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.2     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tibble  3.0.3     ✔ dplyr   1.0.2
✔ tidyr   1.1.2     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
✔ readr   1.3.1     ✔ forcats 0.5.0
── Conflicts ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> c <- (#>1     "Annus Mirabilis"
+ #>2     "Sexual intercourse began"
+ #>3     "In nineteen sixty-three"
+ #>4     "(which was rather late for me)"
+ #>5     "Between the end of the Chatterley ban"
+ #>6     "And the Beatles’ first LP”
+ #>7     "Up to then there'd only been"
+ #>8     "A sort of bargaining",
+ #>9     "A wrangle for the ring",
+ #>10    "A shame that started at sixteen"
+ #>11    "And spread to everything"
+ #>12    "Then all at once the quarrel sank"
+ #>13    "Everyone felt the same",
+ #>14    "And every life became"
+ #>15    "A brilliant breaking of the bank",
+ #>16    "A quite unlosable game".
+ #>17    "So life was never better than"
+ #>18    "In nineteen sixty-three"
+ #>19    "(Though just too late for me)"
+ #>20    "Between the end of the Chatterley ban"
+ #>21    "And the Beatles’ first LP")
+ 
+ library(dplyr)
+ text_df <- tibble(line = 1:21, text = text)
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "library(dplyr) text_df"

Comment: `#` is a comment character, so in the lines that have `#>...` in them, the `...` will not be evaluated. The error happens because you're effectively running `c <- (` followed by `library(dplyr)`. Probably you want something like `text <- c("Annus Mirabilis", "Sexual intercourse began", ...)`, or more directly, `text_df <- tibble(line = 1:12, text = c("Annus Mirabilis", ...))`

Comment: Thanks, Alistaire. I am almost there now:
    library(dplyr)
    Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
   ...
    > text_df <- c(
    + "Annus Mirabilis"
    + "Sexual intercourse began"
    Error: unexpected string constant in:
    ""Annus Mirabilis"
    "Sexual intercourse began""
    > "In nineteen sixty-three"
    [1] "In nineteen sixty-three"
    > "(which was rather late for me)"
   [1] "(which was rather late for me)"

     > "And the Beatles first LP"
    [1] "And the Beatles first LP"
> 
> text_df <- tibble(line = 1:21)
>

Comment: So, for some reason, I am getting the message of an unexpected string constant in the first two lines. But from the third line until the end, everything now appears to be fine.